# How to practice singing without annoying my neighbors?

Tags: voice, practice, soundproofing

I want to practice my singing but I can't do it properly because I have neighbors; my question is, would it work if I made a practicing cubicle with soundproof all around it? I am not sure if soundproof blocks sound going out as well, so if you confirm that for me as well please.

Comment: Your practice should be as similar to an actual performance as you can make it.  Remember, you are practicing not just to know the notes, but to train your vocal tract to produce the sounds you require.  I see an answer below by @Carl that gives some great suggestions for how you might accomplish that without the neighbor problem.  Remember that all neighbors make some noise, so you are not looking for a cone of silence - just sound reduction -  hanging thick blankets in a small space can help with that.   But I like your singing box idea.

Comment: Why should you care at all what the neighors think?

Comment: @NeilMeyer - that attitude often has a nasty habit of backfiring. When I lived next door to noisy neighbours, I made certain it did. Funny, they only seemed happy with their own noise, not mine...

Answer (score 1):

Depends what kind of soundproofing but for singing maybe you'd want somethign with a bit of reverberation (ie not completely dead sound) ?

If so then maybe something harder on the inside layer to reflect some sound back at you, then a layer outside of thick soundproofing panels. That would work both ways - stop sound going out as well as in, but the reflective surface inside would mean it'd probably stop mid-higher pitched frequencies getting out more than getting in (which is what you want).
Bass just rumbles through everything unfortunately but although there's a bit of bass in the human voice, it's not much compared to a bass guitar etc.

To be able to practice while being confident of not bothering your neighbours, you'd probably need quite an efficient soundproof cubicle so make  sure it's sealed properly at all the corners/joints etc - think of it like a bucket of water : any holes will let the water (sound) out.

Have you considered finding somewhere like in the middle of a field/park or something to practice ? Or a studio ?

Comment: +1 on the outdoors.. I'm a terrible singer but I practice in the park down the street.

Comment: I knew someone who used to practice her saxophone in her car, in a car park up on a hill- a popular romantic viewpoint. I daresay it caused a spot of confusion with said romancers. Things went well until a passing police car invited her to move along.

Comment: @user2808054 - wonder what the offence would be racked up as ..? Murdering a song?

Answer (score 1):

There are DIY plans available online to build a "practice cube," or if you're rich you could buy a commercial one :-) .  see for examples,

http://www.drummagazine.com/features/post/DIY-Build-Your-Own-Soundproof-Home-Studio/

http://www.totallyhomeimprovement.com/other-rooms/soundproofing-band-practice-space

https://www.gearslutz.com/board/photo-diaries-recording-studio-construction-projects/673989-diy-rehearsal-room-studio.html